# Where is the Apps key on a standard Microsoft keyboard?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, conemu

[ConEmu has a shortcut](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/KeyboardShortcuts) for renaming the current tab. It's <kbd>Apps</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. I have never seen an <kbd>Apps</kbd> key on any keyboard. Where is it?

Comment: Reference to it by [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm): "Makes the right Alt key become the Apps key (which is the key that opens the context menu)." :)

Comment: Who is reading documentation, really? http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/AppsKey

Comment: Honestly, it's right next to the 'Any' key.

Comment: New link (rip google code) https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> In computing, the *menu key* or *application key* <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>
> is a key found on Microsoft Windows-oriented computer keyboards,
> introduced at the same time as the Windows logo <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> key. Its symbol is usually a small icon depicting
> a pointer hovering above a menu, and it is typically found on the
> right side of the keyboard between the right Windows logo key
> <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
> (or between the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
> key).
>
> While the Windows key is present on the vast majority of
> keyboards intended for use with the Windows operating system, the menu
> key is frequently omitted in the interest of space, particularly on
> portable and laptop keyboards.
>
> The key’s primary function is to
> launch a context menu with the keyboard rather than with the usual
> right-mouse button. It can be used when the right-mouse button is not
> present on a mouse.
>
> Some Windows public terminals do not have a <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd> key on their keyboard
> to prevent users from right clicking; however, in many Windows
> applications, a similar functionality can be invoked with the <kbd>⇧
> Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keyboard shortcut, or sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
>
> Some laptop computers include a menu function on the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key
> (usually
> operated by typing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>); however, this generally invokes
> functions built into the vendor’s software and is not the same as the
> key described above. For example, the Logitech Illuminated Keyboard
> has an <kbd>FN</kbd> key where the menu key is usually found.
> Pressing <kbd>FN</kbd> together with the keyboard’s print screen key
> <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, above <kbd>Home</kbd>
> produces the <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd> key function.
>
> Programmers using the Windows API can intercept this key by looking
> for a WM_KEYDOWN message with wParam VK_APPS (defined as 0x5D in
> `winuser.h`). It has key code 117 (0x75).

**Source:** [Wikipedia - Menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)

> Where is the key located on the keyboard?

On most keyboards it's between the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys.

The key in question typically looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - I did indeed quote and cite an external source.  If you feel there is a problem with this answer.  My suggestion would be to flag it for a moderator to handle. However, this answer was actually submitted 15 seconds before the other answer, which references the same Wikipedia article, so I don't believe it to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 - I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 15):

It's another name for the Menu Key. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key)

It typically has a picture of a right-click menu on it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [ConEmu documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/AppsKey.html):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "APPS" Key is also known as the "Context Menu Key". This may clarify (1) that it does what a right mouse click does, reveal the context menu for the current context and (2) that what you see depends on the context - what has the focus (active in-focus window, selected file/directory tree item, etc.) and (3) for those who sometimes DO make intentional use of the context menu function, what sort of things might be accomplished through the use of the "APPS" key. Also (4) it may suggest the oft-ignored methods for adding more to, or altering the performance of, the context menu's options for the current context.

bon appetite

Answer (score -2):

On my Pavilion g7 it just shows the menu icon without the mouse pointer, but acts exactly like a right mouse click. And yes it is between the right Alt & Ctrl keys.

Comment: This does not really answer the authors question