# Visio Keyboard Shortcut - Context Menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-visio

Is there a keyboard shortcut for accessing the right-click context menu for a shape?

If so, what is it?

Comment: Did you try using the [menu/"apps" key on your keyboard](http://superuser.com/questions/885043/where-is-the-apps-key-on-a-standard-microsoft-keyboard)? It's intended to be used for exactly what you seem to be asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the shape is selected, press the <kbd>context menu</kbd> key.

[image: context menu key]

Or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Function</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd>.