# How to get caret position in a PDF for so I can highlight text using AutoHotKey?

Tags: pdf, autohotkey, adobe-acrobat, sdk, caret

I want to be able to highlight pdf text in Acrobat using only the keyboard (no mouse at all). There is no highlight text hotkey available in Acrobat. So I am trying to do this: use keyboard to select pdf text, then use AutoHotKey to move the mouse near the caret location/position (which will put the mouse cursor on the highlighted text), then I can script [right-click, down, down, down, Enter] to highlight the text.

The problem is that the normal method of getting the caret position in AutoHotKey (A_CaretX, A_CaretY) doesn't work in Acrobat. I don't know how to use the Acrobat SDK and am a novice AHK user.

Can anyone help me solve this problem, either by helping me figure out how to move the mouse cursor near the pdf caret, or through a different method? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the text highlighted, you can `Send::AppsKey`, which will bring up the right-click context menu. **Highlight** should be one of the options, which you can select by sending the appropriate number of *Down* inputs followed by an *Enter*. Or if the **H** in **H**ighlight is underlined for you like it is for me in Acrobat Reader, `Send::h` will also work.

See also: [Where is the Apps key on a standard Microsoft keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/885043/where-is-the-apps-key-on-a-standard-microsoft-keyboard)

The AHK docs mention that A_CaretX/Y plain don't work in certain applications; looks like Acrobat is one of them, though I would be glad to be proven wrong.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for answering. If anyone else is trying to duplicate this, and you want to open a pop-up note after highlighting, shift plus tab after highlighting will select the highlight you just made, And then enter will open a pop-up note.